# Is there a Transaction Scope when PowerShell scripting in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

I've seen that there are transaction scope tools in PowerShell for working with the registry.  But, I also understand that PowerShell providers have to specifically be set up to use transactions.  Does SharePoint (preferably 2010) have something similar to this, or can you use transactions in Management Shell at all?

If not, is there any option to wrap my script in a `try/catch` kind of a tool to ensure that, if an error occurs, the entire script will be rolled back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SharePoint cmdlets themselves do not support such functionality. When an object can be set, it will be set. If not, it will return an error back to the console.